# extracting coordinates from gray scales photos

Tags: matlab, coordinates

Hi I am trying to extract x,y coordinates from gray scale photo (example.jpg). [image: gray scale photo]

I mark the points (with red dots) where I want the x, y coordinates (example1.jpg)[image: dot points for coordinates]

Then I extract the red dots area with below codes

```
A=imread('example.jpg');
B=imread('example1.jpg');
Size=size(A)
C=zeros(Size);
for j=1:Size(2)
    for i=1:Size(1)
           if A(i,j)==B(i,j);
            C(i,j)=1;
        else C(i,j)=255;
        end
    end
end
K=mat2gray(C);
imshow(K)
```

By doing this, I can extract the dots (I am interested) and got below image but the dot points bigger than my real marking in the photo (dots.png). And it did not capture all dots (8 out of 10 dots)

[image: extracted dot points]

Then to get the x,y coordinates of these dot points, I use below codes:

```
 X=imread('dots.png');
 [I,J] = find(X(:,:,1) == 255); %// Change
 scatter(I,J)
```

Then I got x and y coordinates in terms of I,J and the picture to counter check if the coordinates show the correct positions as in the photo.

[image: counter check dot points]

But here are the problems I need solve:

1) How can I get the smaller dot points in figure 3 (as the dot I mark in gray photos are small but when it is generated in figure 3, it become bigger. As a consequence, when I extract x,y coordinates (in terms of I,J here), I got multiple x and y for one dot as each dot is so big. Instead, I want to get one x and one y for each dot.

2) How to make to capture all dots that I mark

3) And when you look at the figure 3 and 4, figure 3 shows the real orientation of pumpkin but in the figure 4, it is rotated. How this happen and how can I correct it?

4) And I thought there can be an easier way to do this extraction than my method. Can you please advice?
Thank you

Comment: have you considered https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ginput.html ? Depending on how you choose the points in the first place, ginput will return the actual x, y pairs for coordinates of points you choose.

Comment: @akamath.. Thanks a lot. It helps me much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a more complete example, for the sake of an answer:

```
I = imread('cameraman.tif');
figure, imshow(I)
[y, x] = ginput(5); % This chooses the five points interactively.

close 
color = I; % making a RGB color version of the image.
color(:,:,2) = I;
color(:,:,3) = I;

for idx = 1:numel(x)
% Change the color of the points to red one by one.
    xpoint = x(idx);
    ypoint = y(idx);
    color(xpoint, ypoint, 1) = 255;
    color(xpoint, ypoint, 2) = 0;
    color(xpoint, ypoint, 3) = 0;    
end

figure, 
imshow(color) % display the colored dot image.
```

This should select five points in the image, interactively, and then color those points red.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of the blobs I suggest that you have saved the image with the red dots using a compressed file format.

The blobs seem to be 24x24 [macroblocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macroblock) - not sure what compression algorithm uses that (not jpeg)...

Here it is one up close:

[image]

Regardless, an easy way to see why it is happening is to list the values of A(i,j) and B(i,j) when A(i,j) != B(i,j) - a basic bug finding process you can do yourself.